# Display list of tables as drop down box

Tags: php

I'm trying to code a drop down box that displays all table names from a database but I can't seem to figure out why it's not working. I'm getting the drop down box on the screen but it seems to be empty and my submit button isn't appearing either.

I just can't see where I've gone wrong, here's all my relevant code:

index.php

```
include_once 'db.php';
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
        <select name="Tables" id="ddTables">
            <?php
                $tableResults = getTableList();
                if($tableResults)
                {
                    if($tableResults->rowCount() > 0)
                    {
                        $tables = $tableResults->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
                        foreach($tables as $table)
                        {
                            $name = $table[0];
                            echo '<option value="'.$name.'">'.$name.'</option>';
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<option value="0">No Data</option>';
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" id="tableSubmit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

db.php

getConnection function:

```
//main database connection varaibles
$DCONFIG_server = "localhost:8888";
$DCONFIG_DBUser = "root";
$DCONFIG_DBPass = "password";
$DCONFIG_DBName = "ISAD235";

try
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$DCONFIG_server;dbname=$DCONFIG_DBName",
            $DCONFIG_DBUser, $DCONFIG_DBPass);
}
catch (PDOException $ex)
{
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}

return $conn;

function getConnection()
{
    //main database connection varaibles
    $DCONFIG_server = "localhost:8888";
    $DCONFIG_DBUser = "root";
    $DCONFIG_DBPass = "password";
    $DCONFIG_DBName = "ISAD235";

    try
    {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$DCONFIG_server;dbname=$DCONFIG_DBName",
                $DCONFIG_DBUser, $DCONFIG_DBPass);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex)
    {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }

    return $conn;
}

function runSQL($sql)
{
    $mysqlConnection = getConnection();
    $ResultSet = $mysqlConnection->query($sql);

    return $ResultSet;
}

function getTableList()
{
    $sql = "SHOW TABLES";
    $ResultSet = runSQL($sql);

    if(!$ResultSet)
    {
        echo "Table list not found";
    }

    return $ResultSet;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: How about a var_dump of $tables ? Also, try moving your else block up one level so it will trigger if the query succeeds but there are 0 rows returned.

Comment: @aviemet doesn't seem to have done anything, var_dump isn't returning anything and neither is my else code. I've tried putting just some echo around the code to see what happens and it seems nothing happens in my <select name="Tables" id="ddTables"></select> for some reason.

Don't know if that helps at all.

Comment: Did you do *Show source code* ?
The output may not display in HTML because it is inside the select tag.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer - Appended the answer, seems I was other thinking the problem, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed my error, it seems I had a port number in my db.php file after localhost. It should have just been "localhost" not "localhost:8888".

3 Hours of problems because of a port number. Oh well hope this helps someone else!